# Most effective way to compare two pairs of integers

Tags: c++, c++11

A class contains two integers; there are two instances of this class. I want to compare them to ensure that the two instances contain the same two numbers (their orders don't matter).

I can do this:

```
bool operator==(const Edge &e, const Edge &f) {
    return ((e.p1 == f.p1) || (e.p1 == f.p2)) && ((e.p2 == f.p1) || (e.p2 == f.p2));
}
```

Is this the best way there is? There will be many such comparisons so I want to make sure I make the most efficient choice. BTW, the operator will be primarily used by the `std::unordered_set` class - in case this information matters.

Comment: Forget about optimization.  I think your logic is incorrect.  These two conditions could be true: (e.p1 == f.p1) (e.p2 == f.p1) and your function would return true without f.p2 even being considered.

Comment: There's no way to optimize this without knowing the details of the use case. For example, are there many, many more comparisons then there are creations of Edges? Can we add extra data to the Edge structure or is memory at a premium? Are these integers immutable for the life of the class instance or can they change? (But most likely, there's no point in optimizing it.)

Comment: If you're worried about the operation being done multiple times, and the order of the numbers does not matter, you might as well just ensure that p1 is always equal to or less than p2, and then you can just compare them directly `e.p1 == f.p1 && e.p2 == f.p2`.

Comment: @SteveWellens Good catch! I can't believe I missed that :(

Comment: If you control the Edge class, can you enforce the constraint that they are always in sorted order?  (I,e, e.p1 > e.p2) Then you would only have to compare them once.

Answer (score 9):

I think you have logic mixed up a bit... if I understand you correctly, given pairs (a,b) and (x,y), you want to check that (a,b) == s(x,y), for some permutation s?

```
bool operator==(const Edge &e, const Edge &f) {
    return ((e.p1 == f.p1) && (e.p2 == f.p2)) ||
           ((e.p2 == f.p1) && (e.p1 == f.p2));
}
```

As for performance... there is nothing to optimize here.  Go look somewhere else if your program is slow.

Comment: "there is nothing to optimize here.  Go look somewhere else if your program is slow" - not so - as rici says it might be worth exploring pre-ordered values; and thereafter e.g. packing the two int32s into a union with an int64 - allowing a single `e.as_int64 == f.as_int64`, which - given the avoidance of short-circuit evaluation, could easily be an order of magnitude faster that your code above.  Of course that might not be significant in the overall context of the program, but the question says "many such comparisons" "want...most efficient choice" - no point answering if ignoring that.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not the fastest, and it requires C++11. But it's nice and short:

```
bool operator==(const Edge& e, const Edge& f) {
  return std::minmax(e.p1, e.p2) == std::minmax(f.p1, f.p2);
}
```

It also suggests an optimization (which I generally use): keep `p1` and `p2` in order so that `minmax` doesn't need to be called every time. Then you do have an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will work ok for two. However, for any more, it obviously gets very ugly very fast. In fact, you'll need to do `n!` comparisons to check when you have `n` variables if you do this in the "naive" way.

An easier way is something like the following:

```
static constexpr Edge::number()
{
    return <number_of_values>;
}

bool operator==(const Edge& e, const Edge& f)
{
    constexpr size = Edge::number();
    std::array<int, size> earr = {{e.p1, e.p2, ..., e.pn}};
    std::array<int, size> farr = {{f.p1, f.p2, ..., f.pn}};
    return std::is_permutation(earr.begin(), earr.end(), farr.begin());
}
```

If it is always two, you can simply write this as:

```
bool operator==(const Edge& e, const Edge& f)
{
    std::array<int, 2> earr = {{e.p1, e.p2};
    std::array<int, 2> farr = {{f.p1, f.p2}};
    return std::is_permutation(earr.begin(), earr.end(), farr.begin());
}
```

Testing unordered equality is the same as testing if one sequence is a permutation of the other.

Edit: Which, as should be obvious to me, can be tested with by checking the sorted sequences are equal. Replace `std::is_permutation` with `std::sort` and `std::equal` in the above, which will be `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: For large sets it will be faster to use `std::sort()`, which is O(N log N), rather than `std::is_permutation()`, which is O(N^2).

Comment: Why not sort them?  Even if you have to copy them to another structure, it's still faster than permutations.

Comment: Is your solution for the case of two values (as i need) any faster than my solution (albeit with corrected logic, thanks to Steve and Dietrich)? Wouldn't involving STL objects be an overkill?

Comment: Eh good point. I just looked up the complexity of `is_permutation`. Didn't actually realize it was `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @deepak No, it's slower, since it constructs intermediate objects. For only two objects, your (corrected) logic is fine. It's more for "if this expands to 3 or more, this way will be far, far more readable".

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question I suggest you following solution:

Just Add on function in your class as below:

```
bool isExist(int point)
{
  if(this.p1==point || this.p2==point)
    return true;
  else
   return false;
}
```

You can apply your logic with calling this function.

Please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: While this is fine, this compares only one element at a time. To comapre both points of the edge i'll have to call twice.